# Independence, Mean, Covariance Matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X, Y)$ be normal distributed with mean vector $\mu=c(1,2)$ and covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right) .
$$
Define $Z:=Y-\frac{\Sigma_{1,2}}{\Sigma_{1,1}} X$ and show that $(X, Z)$ are independent and $(X, Z)$ is normal distributed. Find the mean $\mu_{(X, Z)}$ of $(X, Z)$ as well as its covariance matrix $S$.

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

From what I know, $\Sigma_{1,2}$ = 1 and $\Sigma_{1,1} = 2$. I think that '1,2' just means $1^{st}$ row $2^{nd}$ column and that's why $\Sigma_{1,2}$ = 1 and so on. But I'm not sure how to really solve the question and help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The r.v. $Z$ is normally distributed.

1. $X$ is independent of $Z$: 
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   cov(X, Z) &= cov(X, Y - \frac12 X) \\
   &=cov(X, Y) - \frac12 cov(X, X) \\
   &= 1 - \frac12 \times 2 \\
   &=0
   \end{aligned}
   $$
2. $(X, Z)$ is normally distributed since $X$ and $Z$ are normally distributed and $X$ is independent of $Z$.
3. $EX = 1$, $EZ = EY-1/2 EX=3/2$. and the covariance matrix of $(X, Z)$ is
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   S &= \begin{pmatrix} Var(X) & cov(X, Z) \\ cov(X,Z) & Var(Z) \end{pmatrix} \\
   &= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & Var(Y-\frac12X) \end{pmatrix} \\
   &= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & Var(Y) + \frac14Var(X) - cov(X,Y) \end{pmatrix} \\
   &= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac12 \end{pmatrix} \\
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   Hence,
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix} X\\ Z\end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ \frac32\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac12\end{pmatrix}\right)
   $$

Comment: Zero covariance in general doesn't imply independance.

Comment: @mowzorn Yes, but zero covariance of two normal random variables indicates independence.

Comment: I just added this comment in case someone thought that always $0$ covariance implies independence